# Glottal or Stop /v/?

Tags: consonants, stops, glottal-stop

I am an amateur in linguistics. I was listening to three different British RP pronunciations of the word "massive".

https://www.google.com/search?q=pronounce+massive (Make sure to select British)

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/massive

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/massive_1

Macmill's pronunciation is a clear /v/. Cambridge's pronunciation is more like a devoiced /v/ that sounds close to a /f/. But the one in Google sounds almost like a stop or glottal sound. I don't notice any vibration at all. I know that you can use stop sounds in /d/, /p/, /t/, but I am not sure about /v/ tho.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Stop variant of /v/ is /b/.

Comment: The Google pronunciation is synthetic. It’s a clear /v/ with vibration, but it gets sort of cut off very abruptly sooner than a natural /v/ would be, so it ends up sounding odd. I don’t think it would be humanly possible to accurate reproduce it the way Google’s synthesised speech has it. @Anixx Phonetically, the stop equivalent of /v/ is /b̪/; /b/ would be the stop equivalent of /β/. Systematically, English doesn’t have stop/fricative correspondences at all.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  Thanks. Do people in real world use this stop variant?

Comment: You mean the Google one? No. As I said, I don’t think it’s physically possible for a human to reproduce that sound. There are some forms of English whose speakers may sometimes substitute [b] or [b̪] as an allophonic variant of /v/, but mostly in places where English is historically a non-primary language, like the Caribbean or the Philippines. But other than those, /v/ is generally /v/ everywhere.

Comment: The difference between one and two is speed. Not pronunciation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet if it's physically not possible, then what about the people who are de voicing /v/ to something /f/ like? I find that equally hard to reproduce, and I can find plenty examples of de voicing /v/ in words like "of" by native speakers in real world.

Comment: Devoicing /v/ to /f/ is of course perfectly possible and easy to do – before unvoiced stops, it’s exceedingly common. The thing that’s not physically possible is the mechanic-like cutoff. Anything uttered by a human voice will always trail off, even if just slightly, especially voiced sounds.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't mean a complete de voicing. Something like a half.

Comment: Half-devoicing (where the consonant starts off voiced and becomes unvoiced during its production) is also common, but as far as I know not phonemically contrastive anywhere – it’s just a bi-product of a consonant being positioned between a voiced and an unvoiced element. Polish nasal vowels are said to phonemically start out buccal and become nasal halfway through, but that’s the closest equivalent I know of.